# How to order related objects at first?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Here I want to show navs which are in the role already at first then show remaining navs.

models

```
class MyGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    navs = models.ManyToManyField('Nav', blank=True, related_name='navss')

class Nav(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views

```
class GroupDetailView(View):
    template = 'group_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = MyGroup.objects.get(pk=kwargs['group_id'])
        group_navs = group.navs.all() # display this first 
        navs = Nav.objects.exxclude(pk__in=group_navs) #then display this inside template
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Have you tried iterating over `group_navs` and then `navs` in your template?

Comment: @IainShelvington i want to iterate navs only once at django template if possible ?

Comment: Your desired output is a single queryset/iterable that contains all Nav objects but ordered so `group_navs` are first?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes you are right. Thanks for clearing the question. Is it possible here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an annotation for a `Nav` queryset that resolves as `0` if the group is related to that nav and `1` if it doesn't. You can then order by this annotation

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, IntegerField

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    group = MyGroup.objects.get(pk=kwargs['group_id'])
    navs = Nav.objects.annotate(
        order=Case(
            When(navss=group, then=0),
            default=1,
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    ).order_by("order")
```

Comment: I think it returns duplicate objects ? even using `distinct()` didn't worked

Comment: this is returning duplicate data

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
Nav.objects.all().annotate(group_count=Count('navss')).order_by('group_count')
```

Comment: This orders the `Nav` queryset by the total number of related groups, not by the objects that are related to the `MyGroup` instance first? @D_P